# How to manage spring hierarchy during unit/integration tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-enabled embedded Tomcat application using annotation-based configuration. The application uses Spring MVC Controllers for its REST endpoints. As a separation of concerns, and to avoid having duplicate beans in separate contexts, the parent context contains all beans that are not REST endpoints, and the Spring Web MVC context contains all beans that are REST endpoints.

I want to write new and refactor old integration tests for these endpoints that are representative of the structure of the app. There are existing test classes like so:

```
import com.stuff.web.MyEndpoint;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.stuff"})
public class SpringConfig { ... }

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringConfig.class})
public class TestMyEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private MyEndpoint myEndpoint;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(myEndpoint)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyEndpoint() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/myendpoint")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andReturn();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the context that I am using for this test now has every bean loaded, whereas I would like to ensure that there are not non-REST beans loaded that call into RestController beans during the execution of the tests.

Adding something like

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.stuff"}, 
               excludeFilters = {
                   @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.stuff.web.*")})
public class SpringConfig { ... }
```

Would ensure the kind of separation I'm going for, but then I don't have access to the com.stuff.web.MyEndpoint class that I'm trying to test.

Am I missing something easy? Let me know if I'm explaining the situation clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of separation you're describing (mvc vs non-mvc) made sense 10 years ago, not anymore. Separate your code by functionality/design patterns (web/service/repository etc), and have `@Configuration` classes specific to that layer. The Spring [stereotype annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html) are good enough hint how your app should be broken up. Then, put your tests in the same package as your target code, and mock/override any dependencies.

It doesn't appear you're using Spring Boot (you really should) but they have a great section in the docs for testing "slices" of your application.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests